# First order logic reference request

Tags: logic, reference-request, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

I need a textbook (or any other material) about first order logic, that includes these precise parts: $LK$ sequent calculus, and substitution. I already searched on Shoenfield and Mendelson and I didn't found anything too similar to what we are doing in our course, so I would like to know if there is other valid material.

Comment: [Takeuti](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&printsec=frontcover), [Troelstra & Schwichtenberg](https://books.google.it/books?id=LA_mg2nSbBoC&printsec=frontcover), [Negri & von Plato](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Why don't you transfer your comments to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- G.Takeuti, [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&printsec=frontcover),
- A.Troelstra & H.Schwichtenberg, [Basic Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=LA_mg2nSbBoC&printsec=frontcover), as well as
- S.Negri & J.von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&printsec=frontcover).

You can see also F.Pfenning's [Lecture Notes on Sequent Calculus](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/15816-s10/lectures/08-seqcalc.pdf).